# Basic Proof Involving Set Theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

Let A, B, and C be subsets of a set X.
Prove that $A\cup A^c$= X

I know this is simple and I understand it intuitively but I'm slightly confused on expressing this in a proof. I know that you would have to prove both that $A\cup A^c$ is a subset of X and that X is a subset of $A\cup A^c$. But everything I've done after that hasn't really worked out. Thanks

Comment: This does not make sense.  What do $B$ and $C$ have to do with anything?

Comment: Either $x \in A$ or $ x \not \in A$. If $x \not \in A$ then $x \in A^c$.

Comment: Yes I should have clarified the B and C are not necessary. I think that was from a previous question.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $x\in X$. Then either $x\in A\subset X$ or $x\notin A$. If the first is true, then $x\in X$, and if the second is true, then $x\in A^C\subset X$ and $x\in X$. Thus $x\in A$ or $x\in A^C$ for all $x\in X$, and so $X\subset A\cup A^C$.

Suppose $x\in A\cup A^C$. Then either $x\in A\subset X$ or $x\in A^C\subset X$. Thus $x\in X$, and so $A\cup A^C\subset X$.

Now, since $X\subset A\cup A^C$ and $A\cup A^C\subset X$, $X=A\cup A^C$. $\blacksquare$

Answer (score 0):

Let $x \in X$ and if $x \in A$ then $x \in A\cup A^c$, if not then $x \in A^c$ thus $x \in A \cup A^c$.

Let $x \in A\cup A^c$ then $x \in A$ xor $ A^c$, thus $x \in X$.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose by "set $X$," you mean that $A,B,$ and $C$ are subsets in a universal set $X$ (otherwise, the statement would have to be $A \cup (A^{\mathcal{c}} \cap X)=X $ in order to be true).

The proof would be as follows:

a) $A \cup A^{\mathcal{c}} \subset X$ is trivial, because we defined $A \subset X$, and $X$ representing our universal set implies that if $x \in A^{\mathcal{c}}$ then $x \in X$. Therefore, $A \cup A^{\mathcal{c}} \subset X$.

b) $X \subset A \cup A^{\mathcal{c}}$: By definition, $A^{\mathcal{c}}=\{x \in X : x \not\in A\}$ and $A=\{x \in X : x \in A\}$. This provides that if $x \in X$, then $x \in A$ or $x \in A^{\mathcal{c}}$. Therefore, $X \subset A \cup A^{\mathcal{c}}$.

Thus $ A \cup A^{\mathcal{c}} = X $.